# Object required error '424' when iterating over Collection

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

When I run my function, I get the following error:

```
Run-Time error '424':  Object Required
```

And it highlights the following line of code:

```
For Each n In DataSet
```

Here is my full code:

```
'==============================|Find_Occurrences FUNCTION|=============================='
' Given a collection and a search value, return the number of occurrences of the search
' value in the collection, as an Integer.  If it does not exist, return the integer 0
Function Find_Occurrences(DataSet As Collection, What As Variant) As Integer

    Dim Count As Integer
    Count = 0
    Dim n As Variant
    For Each n In DataSet ''''''''''''''''''Object required error'''''''''''''''''
        'MsgBox (TypeName(What))
        If (TypeName(n) = TypeName(What)) And (n = What) Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next n
    Find_Occurrences = Count

End Function
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this, whether in my code or outside of my code?

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct type of variable in subroutine where you call the function ? The problem is probably in the DataSet which you pass to the function from outside

Comment: Are you sure your collection isn't empty? What does `Dataset.Count return`?

Comment: Agree with @KKowalczyk. What are you passing into the function that you hope to return a count from?

Comment: Thanks!  I just realized that I though i was passing in a collection, but it was actually empty.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer to the question and mark it?  Helps the rest of us who are looking for questions that need attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was actually outside of the function, when the function is called.  Instead of passing in a collection for DataSet, it passes in nothing.